# reCAPTCHA v1 not working with DHIS 2

Tags: dhis2

It seems that Google has stopped support for reCAPTCHA v1 and reCAPTCHA v2 is necessary. I am getting a message "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again".

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

DHIS 2 version 2.28 provides support for reCAPTCHA v2. Please upgrade to DHIS 2 version 2.28 or later. reCAPTCHA v1 is discontinued as of March 2018.

You need to register an account with Google, register your site and retrieve a site key and secret key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/.

The site and secret key must be set up within DHIS 2 from Apps > System settings > Access.

With this you should be able to use reCAPTHA.